# Dividing selected elements of array on Matlab

Tags: matlab, element, divide

I have the following array

```
a = [ 1 10 3 4 68 2 34 8 10 ]
```

And I need to divide each number (/2) if this number is higher than 9.
This means that 1 has not to be divided, and 10 has to be divided (/2)

The resulting array should be:

```
a = [ 1 5 3 4 34 2 17 8 5 ]
```

**I have to do it without using a FOR function. So I tried with this:**

```
a = a./2;
```

This divides every number of the array, and I as told you before, I want to divide only the ones higher than 9.

Can anyone tell me how can I do it? Add a 'if whatever>5' in that statement or something?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use logical indexing for both dividing only the numbers that meets your criterion and for assigning the result to those specific indices.

```
a = [ 1 10 3 4 68 2 34 8 10 ];
a(a>9) = a(a>9) ./ 2
```

Comment: +1 I would store the result of `a>9` in  vector, say `idx`, and use it instead of doing the test twice